# Wordpress plugin doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

Spin360 doesn't work:
All scripts are connected into functions.php

```
  add_action('wp_footer', 'add_scripts'); 
  function add_scripts() {
    if(is_admin()) return false; 
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('remodal', 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js','', '',true); 
    wp_enqueue_script('remodal', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.threesixty.js','','',true); 
    wp_enqueue_script('remodal', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/spinspin.js','','',true); 
  }
```

Jquery.threesixty.js -> http://www.mathieusavard.info/threesixty/demo.html

Spinspin.js:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $("#spin").threesixty({images:["...", "..."], method:'click', direction:'forward', sensibility: 1}); 
  });
```

Article page:

```
  <div id="spin"></div> 
  <script> if (window.jQuery) {
     alert('Connected'); //Return Connected 
   }
  </script>
```

Page -> http://okwood.by/2016/05/iv78-optima/

Comment: You have the path to the jquery script as the first parameter of [`wp_enqueue_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/), but I think it should be the second parameter.

Comment: @PatrickQ thanks, i've fix it, but doesn't have chandeg. also i have pasted '<script> if (window.jQuery) {
  alert('s');
}
</script>' into article and it works

Comment: wordpress uses `jQuery.noConflict()` so `$` is always undefined. Show structure of `spinspin.js`

Comment: @charlietfl i have updated question, please have a look

Answer (score 0):

Since wordpress uses [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) to prevent collisions with any other library that might use `$` alias you either need to replace `$` in your code with `jQuery` or insulate your code in an IIFE like:

```
;(function($){
   // make sure document is ready
   $(function(){
      $("#spin").threesixty({images
   });
})(jQuery);
```

OR

```
jQuery(function($){
   $("#spin").threesixty({images
});
```

Comment: Thank you, i've understand, but now he can't define plugin: spinspin.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).threesixty is not a function

Comment: Either including jQuery.js more than once or forgot to include the plugin file or your code is included before the plugin file

Comment: yeah, i had double-include of script. there are no errors in console but... nothing works. maybe the matter is in plugin? i have no ideas

Comment: Post inventory of all script tags that end up in page itself and in same order they appear in source. Or if page is online post a link to it

Answer (score 0):

WordPress comes pre-packaged with a copy of jQuery, which you should use with your code. When WordPress’ jQuery is loaded, it uses compatibility mode, which is a mechanism for avoiding conflicts with other language libraries.

You can't use `$` in jQuery script, try instead `jQuery` (replace `$` with `jQuery`).

Wrap your code like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
  //Code Here 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress ships with jQuery in noConflict mode but when you load jQuery from CDN I don't think that the case. Another point is that the first param for  [wp_enqueue_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) function is `string $handle`, each handle should be unique. It is also highly recommended to define script dependencies to ensure loading of all the dependencies it needs. Try this example:

```
wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js', [], false, true );
wp_register_script( 'threesixty', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.threesixty.js',[ 'jquery' ], false, true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'remodal', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/spinspin.js', [ 'threesixty' ], false, true );
```

And very important, [wp_enqueue_scripts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) is the proper hook to use when enqueuing items, not `wp_footer`.

Comment: just crashed website)

Comment: Take a look at the page source, jQuery is included twice, in head and body. And i dont see threesixty.js inclued at all, it is probably becouse you use wrong hook to include stuff.